# Is it possible to schedule a task on the Websocket delivery thread?

Tags: multithreading, websocket, jetty

I am using the Whole Message Delivery functionality of Jetty Websockets.
In such a case, [Joakime says](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2690#issuecomment-401796863) that Websocket messages are guaranteed to be delivered in order.

I am going to go on a limb and assume that all Websocket event-handling methods will be invoked by the same thread.

Now, say an external timer expires and I need to send a message over the websocket. The timer runs in one thread and the Websocket events run on a different thread.

Do I need to make my Websocket event handlers thread-safe (seeing as their state will be accessed by the timer and Websocket thread)? Or is there a way for the timer thread to pass a task to the Websocket thread to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jetty WebSocket API (Native or javax.websocket) doesn't care about the thread safeness of the local WebSocket End Point.

It will deliver the next message when it arrives.

Note: you can control [suspend](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/Session.html#suspend()) / [resume](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/SuspendToken.html#resume()) of the read thread with the Jetty Native WebSocket API.

Comment: Updated answer with links to suspend / resume api